# No declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotationDriven'

Tags: spring

This is my servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    classpath:/org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"> 

<mvc:annotationDriven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.ontrollers"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Can someone help me, or instead tell me where I can see my version of Spring?

Comment: you have to use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: See the path of other xsds such as `spring-beans-3.0.xsd`, `spring-context-3.0.xsd`. you are using `classpath` for others and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd` for `spring-mvc-3.0.xsd`

Comment: modified:

          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         classpath:/org/springframework/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
and:
         <mvc:notation-Driven></mvc:notation-Driven>
but the problem is still here :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Not `<mvc:annotationDriven/>` neither `<mvc:annotation-Driven/>` nor `<mvc:notation-Driven>`

Also, don't add explicitly the version of `xsd`